# How to read a JSON file from Assests folder instead of URL in Volley

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-volley

I have a JSON file in the `assets` folder. I'd like to read this file and do something with the data. How can I use Volley for this? I can't find anything like this. I don't want to use more libraries like gson or jackson.

Can I handle it with just Volley?

Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need volley to read a Json file from the asset directory.

In my case, I load an array of Json from the file into my string "filePath".

```
final String filePath = readFromAsset(act, "json_to_load.json"); //act is my current activity
    try {
        JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(filePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = obj.getJSONObject(i);
            // do stuff

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In my utils file :

```
private static String readFromAsset(Activity act, String fileName)
{
    String text = "";
    try {
        InputStream is = act.getAssets().open(fileName);

        int size = is.available();

        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

To be able to use it your have to [import the package "org.json;"](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Volley itself is not able to parse JSON, so you need to use GSON or ...